# Align text to bottom using css

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have a nav bar with an image and a ul. I want to text in the ul to align to the bottom of the div but it at the top right now. How can i achieve this?
http://jsbin.com/otitaf/1/

```
<nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg" id="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="bottom">
                        <a href="home.html">Luigi's ♨  Pizzeria</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="bottom">
                        <a href="#">Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Praises</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

css

```
.logo{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.nav{
    float: right;
}
#logo{
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
.bottom{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting your ul and the positioning, something like this:

```
#side-bar section ul {
position: absolute;
bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use below css to achieve your dream

```
#side-bar{ position:relative; }
#side-bar ul{position: absolute; bottom: 0;}     /*   this will apply to all ul available in side-bar
```

insted this, you can also add class or id to ul to select it specifically, like:

```
.sidebar-ul{position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: @why the #side-bar? The element I want to adjust is the nav